# Can I activate the cat?

Tags: ppkp

In the iOS game PPKP, there is a cat on a roof. If you tap the cat, it shows a little dream of a mouse. Can I find a mouse anywhere and trigger the cat to chase it?

Goofy stuff like that is common in this game, so I thought it was worth a shot.

[image: Cat on roof]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the mouse in the gem store but only after making a purchase (after viewing a short cut-scene). once caught, bring it to the cat, and then it will join you to fight as a pet with you in battle - you can also upgrade the cat over time.

Comment: Add a screenshot plz?

Answer (score 3):

> Also, the cat on top of the restaurant will tell you about its dream
>   of catching a mouse. That’s all the cat does – it’s there for
>   decoration. No secret usage unfortunately.

Source: [PPKP – Answers and Spoilers](https://www.writerparty.com/party/ppkp-answers-and-spoilers-man-in-black-the-cat-how-to-get-to-and-beat-the-final-boss-airport-boss-magic-spells/)